# Integrating to find unknowns of ODE in python

Tags: python, ode, differential-equations

I am new with python spyder and am working on a project where I solve for some unknowns.

the information that I am given is,

y1(0) = 0

y2(0) = 1

dy1/dx = y2

dy2/dx = -y1

I want to find y1 and y2, which are

y1 = sin

y2 = cos solved mathematically.

If you have answers, please be descriptive in why you chose the method that you did... I am really trying to grasp programming as a whole.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `dy1(t)/dt=y2(t)`, `dy2(t)/dt=-y1`, `y1=sin` and `y2=cos`? I have suggested an edit for the question, but if it isn't these, feel free to revert the edit.

Comment: Programming is a tool to achieve something you want. You must first understand what that is. You seem to have been told to use ode, which is for numerical integration. *Solving mathematically* a differential equation is meaningless and *solving for some unknowns* doesn't seem to make sense here. What is it exactly you want to achieve? And have you looked into the documentation for ode?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by mathematically? 
Solving numerically is very simple.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



dt = 0.001
y1 = [0]
y2 =[1]
tlist=[0]
for t in range(10000):
    nexty1 = y2[t]*dt + y1[t]
    nexty2 = -y1[t] * dt + y2[t]
    y1.append(nexty1)
    y2.append(nexty2)
    tlist.append((t+1)*dt)
tlist=np.array(tlist)
y1 = np.array(y1)
y2 = np.array(y2)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(tlist,y1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot(tlist,y2)
ax1.set_title('y1')
ax2.set_title('y2')
```

[image: Y1 and Y2 plot]

Comment: basically, my professor keeps giving me projects and telling me to "learn and gain an understanding of python," yet I have no idea what I'm doing... I do not understand the logic behind any program really, and I'm trying...

The problem he gave was written above, he wanted me to use python to print the initial functions y1 and y2 like you did... Is there any way you can explain how you knew to do what you did, without being given any information?

Comment: Well, the first part to writing any program is to know what it is you want to do. I know how to numerically solve ODEs in principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations#Euler_method for example). This is by far the most important (and first) step. When I have more complex problems to solve, I often write a list of the steps I need to do, on paper before I code a single word. If you can't write a simplified step by step algo of your solution method, you need to figure that out first. If you do not know python or ODEs why are you being set this?

Comment: Because it is something that my professor would like me to gain a simple understanding of, and I understand differential equations mathematically.. I know how to solve them in that way... but solving them through code or however you call what you were able to do... not necessarily my expertice...

Comment: I am not seeing where you got the numbers 211 and 212...?

Comment: The numbers 211 and 212 are the matplotlib api to create two plots in one figure. So I specify a plot of 2 rows, 1 column, and select the plot with the second number. I suggest you invest a weekend in following some basic python tutorials in numpy or vanilla python, google will have a lot of resources.